# MongoDB Query unique values by other fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**td;rd**

I want to get **all the transactions** and ignore the transactions where the pendingTransactionId field is equal to transactionId of **another document**.

---

I have a collection called Transactions and I store documents that represent transactions like Bank transactions. These transactions have a flag that tells you if it's pending and a field that stores the pending transaction id. Here's an example:

```
// Pending Transaction
{
  transactionId: 1,
  pending: true,
  pendingTransactionId: null,
  amount: 5
}

// Processed transaction
{
  transactionId: 2,
  pending: false,
  pendingTransactionId: 1,
  amount: 7
}
```

These are "the same" transactions but I have 2 records of it because the processed one might be processed in a different time (like 1 or 2 days after the pending one was made), and there are fields that might change, like `amount` (for example, this might be a tip that I left in a restaurant).

The query I'm trying to creating and having a hard time is the one that will give me all the transactions but it will ignore the ones that are "duplicate": should ignore a transaction if the pendingTransactionId is equal to transactionId of another document.

---

**UPDATE**

Adding an example of records vs expected

```
// records
{
  transactionId: 123,
  pending: true,
  pendingTransactionId: null,
  amount: 5
}
{
  transactionId: 321,
  pending: false,
  pendingTransactionId: 123,
  amount: 7
}
{
  transactionId: 333,
  pending: false,
  pendingTransactionId: 888,
  amount: 22
}
{
  transactionId: 444,
  pending: true,
  pendingTransactionId: null,
  amount: 50
}
{
  transactionId: 555,
  pending: false,
  pendingTransactionId: null,
  amount: 60
}
```

```
// expected
{
  transactionId: 321,
  pending: false,
  pendingTransactionId: 123,
  amount: 7
}
{
  transactionId: 333,
  pending: false,
  pendingTransactionId: 888,
  amount: 22
}
{
  transactionId: 444,
  pending: true,
  pendingTransactionId: null,
  amount: 50
}
{
  transactionId: 555,
  pending: false,
  pendingTransactionId: null,
  amount: 60
}
```

record with `transactionId=123` is ignored because there's already a transaction that was processed (pending=false). `transactionId=333` isn't ignored because it isn't pending, even if we don't have a record of the pending transaction

Comment: Can you post more samples please. Need to see if we can get desired result with [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/)

Comment: @Valijon added an example

Answer (score 0):

### There is no any native solution...

1. However, we can make the `left join` with itself with the `$lookup` operator, matching the documents by combining `transactionId` and `pendingTransactionId` fields

We may get:

```
a) doc{ pending = false, transaction : [{pending: true}]  } ✔
b) doc{ pending = true,  transaction : [{pending: false}] } X
c) doc{ pending = false, transaction : []               } ✔
```

2. Next stage we filter documents with inner array `transaction.pending = true` or empty `transaction`.
3. With [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/index.html) we exclude field from result document.

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        transactionId: "$transactionId",
        pendingTransactionId: "$pendingTransactionId"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $or: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$transactionId",
                    "$pendingTransactionId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$transactionId",
                    "$$pendingTransactionId"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "transactions"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $let: {
                  vars: {
                    transaction: {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                        "$transactions",
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  in: "$$transaction.pending"
                }
              },
              true
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $size: "$transactions"
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "transactions"
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bMhL2sr5JAu)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get all the transactions and ignore the transactions where
>   the pendingTransactionId field is equal to transactionId of another
>   document.

This is a *self lookup* operation. Finds all transactions which have a parent transaction (transaction with `pendingTransactionId`), as result array for each document. Then remove all documents with parent transaction, in the next stage. In the example documents, `transactionId: 123` has match with a parent `transactionId: 321`.

```
db.test.aggregate( [
 {
    $lookup: {
        from: "txns",
        localField: "transactionId",
        foreignField: "pendingTransactionId",
        as: "parent_txn"
    }
 },
 {
    $match: { parent_txn: { $size: 0 } }
 },
 { 
    $project: { parent_txn: 0 }
 }
] )
```